# Insert FB.Logout to a logout button in other script / Fb.logout not working

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

Ok i read facebook suggestions telling me that the best is to close the facebook session when the user logout from my site.

The info is here:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/#logout

I need to "insert" this action fb.logout to logout button action already working on a file "user_controller" ... i tried to close the session using PHP SDK like this, but this dosent work....

```
function logout_action()
    {



        $srv_nms=BASE;
        $srv_nms=str_replace("http://","",$srv_nms);
        $srv_nms=str_replace("https://","",$srv_nms);
        $srv_nms=str_replace("www.","",$srv_nms);


        $srv_pats=$srv_nms;

        $srv_nms_arr=explode("/",$srv_nms);
        $srv_nms=$srv_nms_arr[0];


        $srv_pats=str_replace($srv_nms."/","",$srv_pats);



        setcookie(COOKIE_LOGINID,"",0,"/".$srv_pats,$srv_nms);
        setcookie(COOKIE_USERNAME,"",0,"/".$srv_pats,$srv_nms);
        setcookie(COOKIE_PASSWORD,"",0,"/".$srv_pats,$srv_nms);

     include("facebook-php-sdk-master/src/facebook.php");
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => '540341239342331',
      'secret' => 'a44c3d3e83b746d7906baaef4b4e045c',
      'cookie' => true,
   ));

   //ovewrites the cookie
   $facebook->setSession(null);


        header("Location: ".$this->make_url("user/login/l"));
        die;
    }
```

Anyway i think is better an easier to add a the function fb.logout to my button that look like this... i have no clue on how to do this.... This is my logout button

```
<a href="http://orsilin.com.mx/index.php?page=user/logout">Cerrar Sesión</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this tutorial to solve your PHP Facebook logout issue - its probably best you review this, so I don't speculate on how the rest of your code is structured:

The link to a helpful facebook login/logout tutorial I have read before, is [here](http://cacovsky.wordpress.com/2011/05/17/login-with-facebook-php-sdk-a-tutorial/)

Comment: thanks so much, i have tried something like that i think, (build the URL to login and logout) the bad thing, is the team wich im working wants (if possible) to stay in the page with the little pop, this other way , redirects to facebook just to do the same but in the hole window... I know its fool. i know its the same .. but im trying to achieve the little pop, anyway if it becomes more difficult im sure i will use this method. thanks.